# Selected image is not shown on canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, redux, fabricjs

I am developing an app where user will get to choose image from the list of images that are provided. When user clicks on the image from the list, the selected image should be shown on canvas as a background. I am developing this using reactjs, redux and fabricjs.

> i dont get selected image when i do
>   this.props.getSelectedImage.image.image so i can update in
>   setCanvasBackground.

**image-list.js**

```
class Images extends React.Component {
  renderImages() {
    const { images, selectImage } = this.props;
    return _.map(images, (image, key) =>
      <li key={key}>
        <img
          src={image.image}
          alt={image.id}
          className="responsive-img default-images"
          width="400px"
          onClick={() => selectImage(image)}
        />
      </li>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="image-list">
        {this.renderImages()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    images: state.images
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ selectImage: selectImage }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Images);
```

**actions.js**

```
export function selectImage(image) {
  return {
    type: 'SELECT_IMAGE',
    payload: image
  }
}
```

**reducers.js**

```
const initialState = {
  selectedImage: require('./img/image1.jpg')
};

export function getSelectedImage(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SELECT_IMAGE':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { selectedImage: action.payload.image })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**image-board.js**

```
class ImageBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      canvas: undefined,
      selected: undefined
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage.selectedImage, canvas);
  }

  setCanvasBackground(image, canvas) {
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(image, function(e) {
    let iw = canvas.backgroundImage.width,
          ih = canvas.backgroundImage.height,
          cw = canvas.getWidth(),
          ch = canvas.getHeight();

    let iar = iw/ih,
      car = cw/ch;

    let nw = cw,
      nh = ch;

    if (iar > car){
      nh = ch;
      nw = nh * iar;
    }
    else if (iar < car){
      nw = cw;
      nh = cw/iar;
    }
    canvas.backgroundImage.width = nw;
    canvas.backgroundImage.height = nh;
    canvas.renderAll();
    }.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="image-board">
         <canvas
           id="canvas"
           className="z-depth-1"
           width={600}
           height={400}
         />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state', state);
  return {
    images: state.images,
    getSelectedImage: state.getSelectedImage
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ImageBoard);
```

Right now i could show the default image but could not change the background image in canvas when image from list is clicked.However when i put `console.log('image selected', this.props.getSelectedImage.image.image);`inside render function i get the selected image but could not set this on setBackgroundImage so i can show the selected image on canvas.

How can i do so?

react v15.4.2 has been used

**UPDATE**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage.selectedImage, canvas);
  }
```

if i use componentDidUpdate lifecycle method, it works but i get the following result. So many canvas are re-created and i know its because i have created an object of canvas in componentDidUpdate to update the canvas. How can i do this in clear way?

[image]

Comment: Without diving too deep into the code, my inkling is that you are adding multiple canvas elements to the DOM with your line `const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');`. Can you check the DOM and see if there are new canvas elements each time you render?

Comment: It is recreating new canvas element everytime i select a new image form the list. I know that is because of componentDidUpdate but if i dont use that the selected image does not appear on the canvas. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential solutions to this:

- Delete the old canvas from the DOM (so you will only have the new one):

[How to destroy / reload the canvas in html 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456160/how-to-destroy-reload-the-canvas-in-html-5)

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    // Get the old canvas and remove it
    var oldCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    oldCanvas = null;

    // Add your completely new canvas
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage.selectedImage,      canvas);
}
```

- Clear the old canvas before redrawing the new one:

[Redrawing Canvas in HTML5 using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773811/redrawing-canvas-in-html5-using-javascript)

To clear the canvas you need to do what was mentioned in the above link. If you are using this approach make sure not to add a new canvas to the page in componentDidUpdate().

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

The link for the second solution specifically mentions that if you don't clear your canvas the drawn elements will stack.

Comment: if i want to clear the canvas then i should call the clear function from componentDidUpdate just before creating a canvas element, right?

Comment: In the case that clears the canvas you could get the old canvas with document.getElementById('canvas') and then clear that in componenentDidUpdate.

Comment: I did componentDidUpdate() {
    const oldCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    oldCanvas.clear();
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    this.setCanvasBackground(this.props.getSelectedImage.selectedImage, canvas);
  }
but i get oldCanvas.clear is not a function error

Comment: it is still the same. You can see in http://www.webpackbin.com/EyVxa6JLf here. But i dont know why i cant use there componentDidUpdate lifecycle, otherwise i get an error of object.render is not a function

Comment: If the canvas is giving you problems, is it possible for you to use the img tag like you do in image-list.js and pass the selected image as props?